# Static block with layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9

I have displayed products in some category page with the help of featured product slider in grid form with static block you can see here (http://demo.wdwil.com/kbd/stone.html), what I need to is I need layerd navigation in the left bar, How Can I do?  please advice.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[ID]` with your category id and add it to any `layout.xml` for exmplate to `app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml`

```
<CATEGORY_[ID]>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</CATEGORY_[ID]>
```

**Upd.1**

I'l give you few pieces of advice how to debug layout.
In most of cases I prefer to add following construction `<remove name="footer" />` to determine is this block workable or not. As result footer should disappear

1. Add inside `<CATEGORY_[ID]>` block from example above (`<remove name="footer" />`). This way you can check that you are in correct category
2. Add inside file local.xml (or some another file which you use) following:

   `<default>`

   `<remove name="footer" />`

   `</default>`

Footer should disappear on every page

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working any other solution?

Comment: Not working what exactly? Anyway look at my updated post and explain your answer what's wrong

Comment: I really appreciate your effort, but I already know in CMS block layout layered navigation is not included, I have talked with theme support, I'm using Intenso theme, they told me I need to add it on CMS pages and in Blocks, Mean while I have tried with category ids to fetched proucts, it will show filter but it didn't work : here is the link (http://demo.wdwil.com/kbd/stone.html)